# Karate - Cucumber reports - How can I get cucumber to generate a unique .html report file each time I run a build

Tags: cucumber, report, karate

In karate, when i run a .feature files, I see the results of previously run feature files as well. How do I get unique cucumber HTML report (overview-features.html) file everytime I run?

Can you please help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you!, it works for karate reports, but can the same thing be done for cucumber reports?